# Saving new lines in a textfield to mysql field

Tags: php, mysql, forms, newline, textfield

Quick and simple (I hope) question; If a user inputs new lines in a text field, ie:

```
43 Dennis

Beeston
```

How can I save the new line rather than have it transferred to the mysql server as one line?!

I am using PHP and mysql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you output the field from the database to a html document, either use `<pre>` or `nl2br()` (or a `<textarea>`).

Comment: Solved my problem too! Thank you for this!

Answer (score 4):

To save the newlines in the database, take a look at [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

If you want your newlines displayed as breaks on the page when you *display* the records, use [nl2br](https://www.php.net/nl2br).

Comment: using <?php echo "$propertyAddr" ?> 
I simply get: 10 Burrows Crescent\r\nBeeston\r\nNottingham\r\n

Answer (score 0):

MySQL should preserve the newline - could it be your output (or your mysql gui) that isn't displaying it?